# S3 access cross-account for assumed role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

having some issues accessing a bucket between 2 account when assuming a role

setup:
Account A:

- id `1111`
- role named `data`

Account B:

- bucket name `lakehouse`

After assuming the role  `data` and running `aws sts get-caller-identity` I get `arn:aws:sts::1111:assumed-role/data/AWSCLI-Session`

The bucket `lakehouse` permissions in `account B` looks like

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::lakehouse/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::lakehouse"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:sts::1111:assumed-role/data/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Issue is I have no access for this bucket

```
> aws s3 ls lakehouse  
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS provides an article on [Cross-Region S3 Access](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3) that could be handy refining your configuration.

In your configuration you use:

```
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:sts::1111:assumed-role/data/*"
                }
            }
```

I am unable to test that, but I am pretty sure that you need to provide the actual role's ARN, not the assumed role's ARN.
Check if the following works:

```
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::1111:role/data"
                }
            }
```

So it is:

```
arn:aws:iam::1111:role/data
```

instead of

```
arn:aws:sts::1111:assumed-role/data/*
```

You can ensure your role's ARN in IAM - I recommend doing that because if your role resides in a path other than `/`, you will have to add that path in policy too, e.g.:

```
arn:aws:iam::1111:role/path/data
```

Comment: worked ! thanks mate .. changing it from 'assumed-role' to 'role' fixed it

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help :)